# How to sort list of floats using brute force algorithm in python

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, brute-force

I am  trying to use `cv2.matchShapes` where I am using dataset of images so when I compare their contours, then store all `ret` values in an float array and images in another one, so the final result that I want is sorted array of images depending on their ret values.
Tried `if rets[i] < rets[i+1]` but got an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float`, Googled about float comparison but didn't solve my problem.

```
import argparse
import pickle
import glob
import sys
from PIL import Image
import os


import cv2
import numpy as np

dataset = "dataset/*.jpg"


# print('image_array shape:', np.array(imageArray).shape)
# cv2.imshow('frame', imageArray[1])
# cv2.waitKey(0)


queryImage = cv2.imread("query/12034.jpg", 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(queryImage, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
queryContour = contours[0]


min_dist = sys.maxsize
images = []
rets = []

for imagePath in glob.glob(dataset):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath, 0)
    ret, th2 = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnt = contours[0]
    ret = cv2.matchShapes(queryContour, cnt, 1, 0.0)

    images.append(image)
    rets.append(ret)


    # if ret < min_dist:
    #     min_dist = ret
    #     images.append(image)
    print(ret)


for i in rets:
    if abs(rets[i] - rets[i+1]):
        tmp = images[i]
        images[i] = images[i+1]
        images[i+1] = tmp
        retTmp = rets[i]
        rets[i] = rets[i+1]
        rets[i+1] = retTmp

print(rets)
```

Comment: `for i in rets` goes over actual values contained in rets, not indexes of those values.

Comment: @Filip Gorgievski Does this help for n, i in rets:?

Comment: @toyotaSupra no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "pair" your 'ret' values with their associated images. Do this with a tuple and build a list of those tuples. You can then sort that list using the built-in. Here's your code edited appropriately:

```
import glob
import sys
from PIL import Image
import cv2

dataset = "dataset/*.jpg"


queryImage = cv2.imread("query/12034.jpg", 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(queryImage, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
queryContour = contours[0]


min_dist = sys.maxsize
rets_images = []

for imagePath in glob.glob(dataset):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath, 0)
    ret, th2 = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnt = contours[0]
    ret = cv2.matchShapes(queryContour, cnt, 1, 0.0)
    rets_images.append((ret, image))
    print(ret)


rets_images.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: @Lancelot du Lac. y: y[0]) or x: x[0])?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Functionally identical